# Predict() function with multinomial GLMM with random effects

Tags: r

I am currently developing a demographic model to project the recovery of corals that were impacted by an oil spill. Corals have branches that can be three different states: healthy, unhealthy or colonized by other organisms. Every year each branch can transition to one of these three states or break. I have measured the proportion of branches that transitioned from one state to another for the same corals (close to a 100 corals) every year for 5 years and would like to use this data to parameterize my demographic model.
I initially tested the effect of three fixed variables (Initial impact, number of associates and coral size) on each transition with GLMM models using a binomial distribution (since I have proportion data - a transition occurs or not) and year of sampling. I ran separate glmm models for each transition. For instance for healthy branches I ran the following models:

```
> nv[1:4,]
  Coral Total Total.nv nv_to_nv nv_to_nh nv_to_hy     Impact Ophiuroid      Size  Site      Year
1    A2    63       63       63        0        0 0.00000000         1 0.7850999 MC294 2011-2012
2    A6   204      201      199        0        0 0.01578898         1 2.8842783 MC294 2011-2012
3   A10   303      108      103        3        2 0.64293344         0 6.4493261 MC294 2011-2012
4   A14    38       36       36        0        0 0.05288091         0 1.1652219 MC294 2011-2012
```

Coral: Individual coral ID
Total.nv: total number of healthy branches
nv_to_nv: number of healthy branches that remained healthy 
nv_to_nh: number of healthy branches that became unhealthy
nv_to_nv: number of healthy branches that became colonized by other organisms.
Impact: Proportion of branches initially impacted

```
yhh <- cbind(nv_to_nv, Total.nv - nv_to_nv)  
modelhh<-glmer(yhh ~ Impact + (1 | Year) + (1 | Coral), family = binomial)

yhi <- cbind(nv_to_nh, Total.nv - nv_to_nh)  
modelhi<-glmer(yhi ~ Impact + (1 | Year) + (1 | Coral), family = binomial)

yhhy <- cbind(nv_to_hy, Total.nv - nv_to_hy)  
modelhhy<-glmer(yhhy ~ Impact + (1 | Year) + (1 | Coral), family = binomial)
```

I then used the predict() function to predict each transition independently for different values of Impact, and used these values for my demographic model.

I know this is inaccurate because I used separate glmms treating each transitions as if they were independent, which is not the case.
I think that I need to model these transitions using a multinomial distribution instead of binomial and I do not think that the lme4 package offers this option. I looked at the mlogit() and multinom() functions but none of them seem to allow for categorical random effects.

I found that multinomial glmms are possible with the MCMCglmm() function and I was wondering if anyone had experience using the predict() function with multinomial glmms.

I also considered modeling my transitions as a series of binomial models for each contrast (“Begg and Gray Approximation”). Then again I was wondering if it is possible to make predictions with this methods.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't used the `MCMCglmm` package, but I would expect that `predict` works in a similar way as with other models. You can look at the documentation for the `predict` method for `MCMCglmm` model objects by loading the `MCMCglmm` package and running `?predict.MCMCglmm`.

Comment: Same here, but every glm model in lme4 that I have used implemented a version of this [this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html) `predict()` function.

Comment: Thank you @eipi10. Actually I have tried to use the predict() function but always get the same error message: `Error in MCMCglmm(fixed = object$Fixed$formula, random = object$Random$formula,  : Singular G/R structure: use proper priors`. I know my prior is fine because the model works so I am still figuring this out. I have seen comments on other forums about the function not being adapted for multinomial fits so I was wondering if someone could confirm whether it works fine or not.